# Multiple Intent flags for starting a new Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, flags

I'm trying to add more flags at an Intent for launching a new Activity inside a BroadcastReceiver, responding to a particular intent sent from another part of the app.
I've added as I noticed by the LogCat messages the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag at the Intent I created and then other ones but I get the same error in LogCat as the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` was not there.

Here's the code:

```
 public class actReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 ...
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    ...
     else if (intent.getAction().equals("something")) {
                Intent prefAct = new Intent(context, PreferencesActivity.class)
                prefAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                       .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS)
                       .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                       .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                startActivity(prefAct);
            }
     ... }
... }
```

And the particular LogCat error:

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setFlags` just assign the argument, as you can see from the snippet

```
public Intent setFlags(int flags) {
    mFlags = flags;
    return this;
}
```

so in your case you are just assign the last one. To fix it put it on or

```
 prefAct.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

or use `addFlags` which does the same thing

```
public Intent addFlags(int flags) {
    mFlags |= flags;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `addFlags()` instead of `setFlags()` to add additional flags.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int)

`setFlags()` sets the complete set of flags to be used, so you would have to `|` all flags to be used in here. `addFlags()` can be called multiple times, and does the `|` of flags for you.

Answer (score 0):

simple way of doing it with kotlin and anko see snippet 
[see example snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0jYf.png)

startActivity(intentFor().clearTask().newTask().noHistory())

hope this helps